# Initializing a structure

Tags: c, struct

gcc 4.5.1 c89

compiling with the following flags: `-Wall, -Wextra`

I have the following structure that I am trying to initialize with default values. However, I get the following warnings:

```
static struct Device {
    char *name;
    char *config;
} *app = { NULL, NULL };
```

Warnings:

```
warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
```

However, if I do the following by declaring a non-pointer, I don't get any problems i.e.

```
 static struct Device {
        char *name;
        char *config;
    } app = { NULL, NULL };
```

Why is that?

Many thanks for any advice,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't initialize a pointer that way. You can do this though:

```
static struct Device {
    char *name;
    char *config;
} *app = NULL;
```

Initialize a pointer to `NULL`. A pointer is nothing but a memory address. You can't assing `{ NULL, NULL }` to a memory address.

Answer (score 2):

A pointer is not a structure but a simple type whose value is an address.

- If your `app` variable is of pointer type, it may be initialized with `NULL` but not with the braces syntax you use
- If the `app` variable is of type `struct Device`, you may use the brace initializer to provide an initial `NULL` value to the `name` and `config` fields

Answer (score 2):

because *app is a pointer so initializing it to { NULL, NULL } is wrong, you should initialize it to simply NULL.

in the case of app you have an actual variable instance of the struct so there you initialize the members of the struct to NULL, that is OK.